# How to find out which Port number a process is using

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ubuntu, terminal

I want to be able to find out which port number a process is and filtering the results using a keyword.

For example, I may want to quickly find out which port numbers are being used by "node" js apps.

This did not work:

```
netstat tulnap | grep "node"
```

This did not return the port numbers:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Comment: Did you try just netstat -anp | grep node

Comment: By the way, i notice that on osx the command doesnt have a hyphen. Here are the results i got, not useful:
Address          Type   Recv-Q Send-Q            Inode             Conn             Refs          Nextref Addr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I found a solution:

```
     » lsof -i -P  | grep node
    node      14489 me   12u  IPv4 0x...      0t0    TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)
```

Also if i knew the port and I was looking for the process name I would:

```
     » lsof -i :4000
    COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    node    14489 me   12u  IPv4 0x...      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)

```
netstat -pnt
```

Active Internet connections (only servers)

```
netstat -pntl
```

Answer (score -2):

What you're doing may also never work since GREP is never guaranteed to deliver either no, one, or more than 1 results.

But, in context of your specific case, any process IS actually unique, and has a unique number. So, you must do your search first to find a process number.

Doing a simple grep will still give you either none, one, or more than one process number. But you'll need to find an additional  filter, so that you end up with 1 process number.

If you have 1 process number, you can check port(s) being used by that process.

What makes you think "node" is reported in PS ? It may also not be.